# Count number of times a value is true Advanced Custom Fiess

Tags: php, html, arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am currently using ACF on my Wordpress site and have a checkbox field with Yes and No in my Sub Field 'Result'. My ACF fields are only used in a Custom Post Type called 'Tips'.

I would like to count the number of times 'Yes' occurs and the number of times 'No' occurs in my specified field in the CPT 'Tips'.

Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction to solve this issue.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tools';echo '

  ';foreach($rows as $row){if (get_sub_field ('show_desktop') == true ) {echo count(get_sub_field ('show_desktop',true));}else {echo count(get_sub_field ('show_desktop',false));}}echo '

';} 
?>